# CiviEvent online registration with multiple participants - move Payment Options to end

Tags: civievent

When signing up for an event with multiple participants, the Payment Options appear after the profile forms for the person signing up for the event. You have to choose the payment option you want, then click Continue, in order to add the additional participants. This can be confusing since it feels like payment is about to be taken, when the final registration amount will not be known until details for all participants have been entered.

Is there a way to move the Payment Options to the end of the process, i.e. after all the participant details have been entered?

Comment: I have found a variation (workaround?) on the problem above.

On sites where the credit card processor uses a hosted payment page, you are required to choose your payment preference on the first page but you aren't redirected to the offsite payment page until after the Confirmation page. 

In this scenario, the amount sent to the payment processor is the correct amount based on the attendance of all participants.

Comment: Agreed, in all other web applications, payment info is collected at the end. This makes it extremely confusing. The "Register multiple participants" option is unusable until this is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem ;
Moreover, the price set is repeated for each participant, beyond payment, which is useless and confusing.
I fully agree with a move to the end of the process, when everything is known.

Answer (score 1):

I also have seen the same problem, The Person registers with their name and then selects and pays for accommodation. We have to explicitly tell them to select the No accommodation at 0$ when they register their spouse.