# CiviEvent online registration with multiple participants - Only 1st Registration Being Charge via PayPal Checkout

Tags: civievent

I'm facing a similar problem with multiple civievent registrations as [CiviEvent online registration with multiple participants - move Payment Options to end](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10664/civievent-online-registration-with-multiple-participants-move-payment-options). With a single registration, everything, including PayPal Checkout works. I've moved the PayPal payment processor to the bottom of the register.tpl page so that all of the needed data is collected prior to payment. When the option to have 2 or more participants registered, the PayPal Payment Processor shows up on the bottom to the on-line registration page as soon as the selection is made, which isn't grate but workable. After the data for the first person is entered the PayPal payment has to be processed, with just the fees for the first person in order for the 'continue' option to show and for the second person's data can be entered. After the second person's data, including selected fees for them the registration form can be reviewed/processed. It shows the fees for both the first and second person, but only the fees for the first person have been processed by PayPal.

Is there a way move the PayPal Checkout payment process to the end of registration form so that the total payment due (e.g. individual fees for both the first and sequent persons registering) is sent to PayPal. The way it's working now is that only the first person registered is charged. Joomla Ver 3.9.2 CiviCRM ver 5.34.0. TIA...

Comment: thx. i deleted the other one

Comment: Quick question - do you have the confirmation page enabled and does it show the total amount correctly?

Comment: Yes, the confirmation page show the total for multiple registrations, even when the 2nd registration hasn't been charged. It also shows both when the 'pay later' options is selected.